# <type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: cannot import name service_handlers

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I built a web app a month ago and then tested it. It had been working fine during last month without any code modifications but suddenly today I saw there an error occurring permanently.

```
<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: cannot import name service_handlers
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/infinillaapp/1.351169771270370877/services.py", line 10, in <module>
    from protorpc import service_handlers
```

I tried to import the module different ways but nothing helped. So, I suppose there is something wrong with the GAE environment? Also, it works fine as before on the local machine. Did anybody face such unexpected module import problems with GAE?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>This is a bit of a guess; but I think</strike> [protorpc is going to be included in AppEngine 1.5.1](https://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/767a446a246fc6e4), maybe they have added it in the background somewhere and it's conflicting.

Try adding the protorpc path to the beginging of sys.path:

```
sys.path = ['protorpc'] + sys.path
```

Also, try updating protorpc to the latest version to see if you get the error locally as much of the GAE specific code has moved. The new import should be:

```
from protorpc.webapp import service_handlers
```

Comment: the second option alone worked 
from protorpc.webapp import service_handlers

Answer (score 3):

Chris is right - the `service_handlers` file has moved to the `webapp` module. You can just use

```
from protorpc.webapp import service_handlers
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to depend on your own private version you can also [set up your pythonpath](http://groups.google.com/group/google-protorpc-discuss/browse_thread/thread/d7e3749420168a5b) to make it so.